# Why in node exist more than one way to export?

Tags: node.js

In node.js we can use

- module.exports
- exports

`exports` is shorthand for `module.exports`.

In my opinion, providing `module.exports` and `exports` is confusing.
It is not only confusing but error prone also because we can reassign one.

Why `module.exports` is not the only way to export?
What was the goal to provide both?

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_exports_shortcut) says it's so that code writing to `export` can be more concise:

> **`exports` shortcut**
>
> The `exports` variable is available within a module's file-level scope, and is assigned the value of `module.exports` before the module is evaluated.
>
> **It allows a shortcut, so that `module.exports.f = ...` can be written more succinctly as `exports.f = ....`**

*(my emphasis)*